# toggle between old (lowercase) and classic (uppercase) style numbers?

Tags: fonts, typography, kpfonts

I use the `kpfonts` font package, and I would like to use `oldstylenums` as default, but in tables showing data or graphs, I would like to use the classic (uppercase) letters. Instead of using the command `\classicstylenums` (provided by `kpfonts`) on each number, I would rather use a toggle command. I can switch from old to classic numbers successfully, but I can't revert them. MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\def\allnums{01234567890}

\makeatletter
\def\togclsnums{\fontfamily{jkp\kp@stylemath\kp@famillem}\selectfont} %% from kpfonts.sty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

default, old: \allnums\\
command to switch to classic: \classicstylenums{\allnums}\\
command to switch to oldstyle: \oldstylenums{\allnums}


\togclsnums %% works

\allnums\begin{tabular}{l}\allnums\end{tabular}

\meaning\oldstylenums ???

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to limit the scope of `\togclsnums`, just surround it and whatever numbers should be in the scope of the directive with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements.

Comment: Definitely doable, but I'd still love the toggle (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can load the `kpfonts-otf` package, which enables the `oldstylenums` and `\liningnums` commands of `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts-otf}
\def\allnums{01234567890}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

default, old: \allnums\\
command to switch to classic: \liningnums{\allnums}\\
command to switch to oldstyle: \oldstylenums{\allnums}

\allnums\begin{tabular}{l}\allnums\end{tabular}

\meaning\oldstylenums

\end{document}
```

If you really, truly want a toggle, you can use `\addfontfeature{Numbers=Lining}` or `\addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle}`.

With the legacy 8-bit font package, the lining and old-style numbers are in separate NFSS font families, which are documented in section 5.1 of the `kpfonts` manual.  You want to declare commands to change font families.  Here, I’ve used the same commands as `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\def\allnums{01234567890}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\kproman@osf@on}{\fontfamily{jkposn}}
\newcommand{\kproman@osf@off}{\fontfamily{jkp}}

\DeclareTextFontCommand\oldstylenums{\kproman@osf@on\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\liningnums{\kproman@osf@off\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

default, old: \allnums\\
command to switch to classic: \liningnums{\allnums}\\
command to switch to oldstyle: \oldstylenums{\allnums}

\allnums\begin{tabular}{l}\allnums\end{tabular}

\meaning\oldstylenums

\end{document}
```

This always gives you the KP Roman numerals, and should work with the various font weights and shapes.  It would be much more complicated to write a version that can add this feature orthogonally with either serif or sans-serif.

Comment: Sigh, how the heck did I not know about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is far from being thoroughly tested (cases with `oldstylemath` for example), but this does the trick for me:

`\def\togoldnums{\fontfamily{jkplosn}\selectfont}` if you are using the light option

`\def\togoldnums{\fontfamily{jkpxosn}\selectfont}` if NOT using the light option.